# How do I set the cell values in one dataframe based on the values in two other dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have three dataframes with the same shape, illustrated by the contrived data below. I want to iterate across df1 and set the value of each cell in the signals dataframe to 1 if the cell value in df1 is greater than the corresponding cell value in df2. Can someone illustrate how to accomplish that?

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI']
prices = [[12.22, 14.34, 98.34], [12.52, 15.34, 96.34], [13.12, 14.73, 97.47]]
prices_df1 = [[16.11, 18.12, 19.13], [16.21, 18.22, 19.23], [16.31, 18.32, 19.33]]
prices_df2 = [[12.22, 18.34, 17.34], [17.52, 18.34, 19.34], [13.12, 14.73, 16.47]]
mydates = ['09-15-2018', '09-16-2018', '09-17-2018']


signals = pd.DataFrame(index=mydates, columns=cols, data=0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=mydates, columns=cols, data=prices_df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=mydates, columns=cols, data=prices_df2)
```

how do I set the signals dataframe to have a 1 if df1 > df2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a fast boolean filter.

```
# better speed if boolean to integer conversion is separate from
# the boolean comparison
signals = (df1 > df2)
signals = signals.astype(int)

print(signals)

           ABC DEF GHI
09-15-2018   1   1   0
09-16-2018   1   1   0
09-17-2018   1   1   0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use df.where

```
signals = signals.where(df1 < df2).fillna(1).astype(int)
signals


           ABC  DEF GHI
09-15-2018  1   1   0
09-16-2018  1   1   0
09-17-2018  1   1   0
```

Comment: If I want to insert a "1" when df1 is greater than df2, why does the expression use ```(df1 < df2)``` rather than ```(df1 > df2)```? It seems to be the opposite of what I expected.

Comment: I think I get it, the logic filter creates nans and then they get stuff with 1 by the fillna.